# PCB design for a circuitry with two HVDC

Tags: pcb-design, hvdc

I am a freshman and for our project, we have to deal with a simple circuitry, that contains two DC power sources- 10kV and 650V.
I want to design the circuitry in the KiCAD, but I don't understand which material should be used for the PCB. Is this thing feasible to design? I am really confused.

Comment: Do you have any specific question? 10 kV does not sound like simple circuitry. Please be careful.

Comment: If you're a freshman and wanna work with 10 kV, I'm stunned and so could you literally be. I very much advice against this.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't explain it. The circuit seems simple when you look at it! It worked fine when I used a wooden board, and copper bus bar. But, everything was exposed and I need to enclose it. However, I don't understand and realize whether it is feasible to compact the whole circuitry in the PCB.

Comment: I'm thinking a single sided PCB is better suited, and keep a wide clearence for tracks.

Comment: Please show a photo of the existing circuit. Along with a schematic.

Comment: Nothing involving 10 kV should be considered simple. There's a lot of complexity in merely making sure the circuit doesn't arc and destroy itself.